# Error when using foreach on dictionary which contains objects as value

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, foreach, enumeration

I'm trying to iterate over a dictionary which contains objects as value:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, CMapPool_Entry> Entry in MapPool)
{
   this.SendConsoleMessage(Entry.Value.Map);
}
```

Below you can see the class of CMapPool_Entry

```
public class CMapPool_Entry
{
    public string Map;
    public string Mode;
    public int Rounds;
    public int Index;
    public int Votes;

    public bool Nominated;
    public string Nominator;

    public CMapPool_Entry(string map, string mode, int rounds, int index, string Nominator_LeaveEmptyStringIfNone)
    {
        this.Map = map;
        this.Mode = mode;
        this.Rounds = rounds;
        this.Index = index;

        // If Nominator isn't empty, set map to nominated
        if (Nominator_LeaveEmptyStringIfNone != "")
        {
            this.Nominated = true;
            this.Nominator = Nominator_LeaveEmptyStringIfNone;
        }
    }

    public void AddVote()
    {
        this.Votes++;
    }

    public void RemoveVote()
    {
        if (this.Votes > 0)
            this.Votes--;
    }
}
```

Here you can also see the SendConsoleMessage method:

```
    private void SendConsoleMessage(string message)
    {
        this.ExecuteCommand("procon.protected.pluginconsole.write", String.Format("{0}", message));
    }
```

To me it looks like it would work, I've read about how editing values from a dictionary inside a foreach would give the following error: "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

But why do I get this error? I'm not editing any values, I'm just reading them right? It works fine if CObject was string or int instead, but if it's an object it goes nuts. 
What am I doing wrong, what should I do?

---

EDIT: After further debugging I've noticed that Entry.Key is fine to use, but as soon as I touch Entry.Value I receive errors. I've gotten two different errors randomly for some reason:

1. "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."
2. "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Any ideas? Or does enumerating dictionaries with objects as value just simply not work?

Comment: Can you post the code of the `CObject.SomeVariableInObject` property getter?

Comment: you are trying to update the ExampleDictionary in SendConsoleMessage method..

Comment: @Rao, but then the error would also occur if the dictionary's value type was `string` or `int`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I added the whole CObject class (though it's not actually called that).

Comment: What does `ExecuteCommand` do? Does that modify the collection somehow?

Comment: @JonSkeet Nope. ExecuteCommand has absolutely nothing to do with what I'm programming on, it is merely a function to send messages or commands to Procon (Frostbite Admin tool). I can use another method which does absolutely nothing and I will still receive the error. =/

Comment: Is this a single-threaded app? If you're getting the errors randomly, it could very well be that you're sharing the dictionary and it's getting modified by some other thread.

Comment: @millimoose Good thought, but no it couldn't be. The Dictionary is copied before it's used in the foreach loop, like so: "Dictionary<int, CMapPool_Entry> MapPool = this.Votemap_MapPool;" No other thread could change that local dictionary.

Comment: You are not copying the Dictionary that way, you are simply leaving a reference to the Dictionary. So if `Votemap_MapPool` gets modified the reference, which `MapPool` holds, gets modified accordingly. To copy the dictionary do `Dictionary<int, CMapPool_Entry> MapPool = new Dictionary<int, CMapPool_Entry>(Votemap_MapPool);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As everyone indicates in the comments you are modifying the dictionary in another thread while you are trying to read from it. You wrote in the comments that you "copy" the Dictionary by writing:

```
Dictionary<int, CMapPool_Entry> MapPool = this.Votemap_MapPool;
```

This does not copy the dictionary, but creates a reference to `Votemap_MapPool` in `MapPool`, hence when modifying `Votemap_MapPool` somewhere in your code, while reading `MapPool` you will get the exception `System.InvalidOperationException` with the message that the Collection was modified.

To really copy your dictionary you have to write:

```
Dictionary<int, CMapPool_Entry> MapPool = new Dictionary<int, CMapPool_Entry>(Votemap_MapPool);
```

This really creates a new instance of the Dictionary with `Votemap_MapPool` as contents, and when `Votemap_MapPool` gets modified, `MapPool` is untouched.

Comment: Oh jeez now I feel like a fool. But cheers mate that did the trick. ;D

Comment: @MattiasKristiansson: That constructor *also* iterates over the source dictionary. So you should also synchronize access to it while copying. (Same probably goes for using ToArray() etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the collection (dictionar is collection too) during processing foreach.

Workaround:

```
using System.Linq;

foreach (CObject value in ExampleDictionary.Values.ToArray()) {
   this.SendConsoleMessage(value.SomeVariableInObject);
}
```

Comment: I've seen this workaround before, but I don't understand why it would be necessary. The SendConsoleMessage(string message) method shouldn't be able to change anything afaik? Why does it still work if the KeyValuePair is <int, string>?

Comment: Imho somewhare in call stack in SendConsoleMessage() changes the ExampleDictionary. Without the source code is imposible say where is the problem.

Comment: I've added the source for that method.

Comment: What StackTrace is in the thrown exception?

Comment: Nothing, it just tells me "No Source Available". All I can find is this: System.InvalidOperationException was unhandledMessage=Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.Source=mscorlibStackTrace:at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Enumerator.MoveNext()at PRoConEvents.CSynergy.Votemap_SelectMap()at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()InnerException:

Comment: Is posible, that during you do "foreach" in paralel thread, some other thread modify the collection?

Comment: No, see my response to millimoose.

Comment: As @Cheesebaron said, you are not copying the dictionary. I bet the issue will be made by accessing the dictionary from multiple threads.